# create dynamically web user control from a simple cs file (not aspx.cs ) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrols

I am writing an web app in asp.net using .net 3.5 and vs 2010;

I creatd a web user control (.ascx), and i want to insert it to a panel taht i created in a simple cs class (not a aspx.cs),

my class is in App_Code, the problem is that the class dous not Identifies the user control name so for example i cant do:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { }

    public void foo(MyCtrl i_MyCtrl)

    {
       //doing somthing 
    }  
}
```

I search for an answer on the web, and people say it cant be done in .net 2 and vs 2005/8 but nothing about .net 3.5 and vs 2010

the thing is that you cant create a butten (a buttten is a control) ,  so this make me think maybe there a chance to create a dynamically user control in a simple cs file.

please helpe

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The LoadControl method reads in a given ASCX and constructs a Control instance from it - you are then free to add it to the page's control tree. This has been a feature from the beginning in ASP.NET:

```
Control c = this.LoadControl("myAscx.ascx");
this.myPanel.Controls.Add( c );
```

Comment: this did not work i get an error: System.Web.HttpException: The file '/WebSite/WebUserControlTest.ascx' does not exist. for :      Control c = this.LoadControl("~/WebSite/UserControls/WebUserControlTest.ascx");